# MS ChatBot Failed to load image

Tags: azure, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot

MS ChatBot (NodeJS) running on Azure ignores an image that i'm trying to load in Facebook's Messenger.
while running stand-alone, not via Facebook, it's working fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922)

Comment: @Barak - When you say that it works stand-alone, do you mean the image is displayed when testing with the Microsoft Bot channel emulator?

Comment: @Guenther - The question falls well within the software development scope of Stack Overflow, the OP should however provide more detail as you indicate.

Comment: @camelCase - when i open the chat directly - the image displayed good.

Comment: @Barak - We must be using the Bot Framework differently because I do not understand what "open the chat directly" means. If you need further help I suggest you post some code similar to this other related SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945039/send-an-image-attachment-in-microsoft-azure-chatbot?rq=1